# Equal, sum or difference!

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Write shortest possible code that will return true if the two given integer values are equal or their sum or absolute difference is 5.

Example test cases:

```
4 1 => True
10 10 => True
1 3 => False
6 2 => False
1 6 => True
-256 -251 => True
6 1 => True
-5 5 => False
```

The shortest I could come up with in python2 is 56 characters long:

```
x=input();y=input();print all([x-y,x+y-5,abs(x-y)-5])<1
```

-9, thanks @ElPedro. It takes input in format x,y:

```
x,y=input();print all([x-y,x+y-5,abs(x-y)-5])<1
```

Comment: welcome to PPCG! This is a good first challenge -- the challenge is clearly defined, it has ample test cases, and uses our default I/O! If you stick around for a while and keep thinking up interesting challenges, I would recommend using [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback before posting them to this site. I hope you enjoy the time you spend here!

Answer (score 27):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a in(b,5-b,b-5,b+5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUSEzTyNJx1Q3SSdJ11QnSdtU839BUWZeiUaahqGOiaYmF5xnoGNogMzXMUbimekYociZIfF0jUzNdICEoabmfwA)

<sub>One byte saved by Arnauld</sub>

<sub>Three bytes saved by alephalpha</sub>

Comment: This is amazingly concise, thanks

Comment: Same can be done in Octave/MATLAB in 29 bytes ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTMxr1Ij0dY2OknbVMFAIUnXVMFUNylW83@ahoKCgokOkDDUVFBVsLVTCCkqTeUCCRsa6IAIdGEFQ5BqY6iwW2JOMVTcDCRuhCkOVm@GaoyukamZDpDAsBRiCoawrilI2BTZ8P8A "Octave – Try It Online")).

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
a=>b=>a+b==5|!(a-=b)|a*a==25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1i5RO8nW1rRGUSNR1zZJsyZRK9HW1sj0f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGiaaGoaamAhTo6yuEFJWmcqGqMTTQBGFNvGo0NYxRzHFLzClGV2SmqWFEUBHQJDNCLtI1MgWaBSTBboeq@Q8A)

Comment: Damn, took me a long long time to figure out how this handling the difference part. :)

Answer (score 11):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
=∨5∊+,∘|-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTbRx0rTB91dGnrPOqYUaP7/7@JQpqCIZehAYgy4DIEUsZcZkDSCMw24zq03sgUxAfRhlzq6iABMNcYAA)

Spelled out:

```apl
  =   ∨  5      ∊                +   , ∘    |            -
equal or 5 found in an array of sum and absolute of difference.
```

Answer (score 8):

## x86 machine code, 39 bytes

```
00000000: 6a01 5e6a 055f 5251 31c0 39d1 0f44 c601  j.^j._RQ1.9..D..
00000010: d139 cf0f 44c6 595a 29d1 83f9 050f 44c6  .9..D.YZ).....D.
00000020: 83f9 fb0f 44c6 c3                        ....D..
```

## Assembly

```bash
section .text
	global func
func:					;inputs int32_t ecx and edx
	push 0x1
	pop esi
	push 0x5
	pop edi
	push edx
	push ecx
	xor eax, eax

	;ecx==edx?
	cmp ecx, edx
	cmove eax, esi

	;ecx+edx==5?
	add ecx, edx
	cmp edi, ecx
	cmove eax, esi
	
	;ecx-edx==5?
	pop ecx
	pop edx
	sub ecx, edx
	cmp ecx, 5
	
	;ecx-edx==-5?
	cmove eax, esi
	cmp ecx, -5
	cmove eax, esi

	ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNj5swED3jXzFCShUSkw/S5JCEjVS1q16qvfTWjSJjzMYrYiNsWrZVfns6ht0k7AaBPW/83swwAwkz@xNnFtbrbw/3cAdjeyjGbMTM4WQEt1IrGFlRW@I95TphOWSV4sQtS89dK6mKyhqQys6inQXBa2AqBZHWxCsqs4dJPUVLFyCMPLvmr670zXXhYwTi1boEwWrqFkK8FTrjGDkb4vFD4Ti0lfCD/i1eqRi/pQ7xKI7nSGZp2iE3KWmb453Ua7XhWdsU6IhtpWiYKnkfzaF5VxvONx@Dn8nh/EbRpbAn7D8hH0ZhbJWMOMEJiFK5LsNux6wtZVJZsdv1@xkzlrM8D4JmNH2kUHyCFZADk6of/COek1lhrPm1jRF6n@mU4jadULydQWduW9CoRQu3hdF8QXGZtkc4xOOKeJkuXQqQ8WQl10b@FTrrN7GD8StqssthHLnUXlEizvp@L6W9dAk986h82hYjt2/GcLqlTfU3DoKN/7OshL/071luhB9gFUdyJE2/FH6oEGYiz2bR1bcLoW4R16kYafLEedeFguv@XpMhVDospIDwMIuITp65Ll4gfIBEKlai9dz@ER3NxUYWcaq0womHXyH84aYm8g797lNEBN9jLgH@oxoMBl9erACuK2WXiPyG8QeL5rDuBr@h/S5ql@0irOv0hoh0Xv/0Hw)

Edit: fixed bash stderr errors on TIO

Edit 2: improved formatting in TIO header and footer code

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
+,ạ5eo=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19b5@Guhaap@bb/Dy830leI/P9fQ0FBwUQHSCgY6nCBSAMdCMkFEQORxhCOGZhjhCxjBuToGpkCZYAk0ABNAA)

#### How it works

```
+,ạ5eo=  Main link. Arguments: x, y (integers)

+        Yield x+y.
  ạ      Yield |x-y|.
 ,       Pair; yield (x+y, |x-y|).
   5e    Test if 5 exists in the pair.
      =  Test x and y for equality.
     o   Logical OR.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>29</s> 31 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a+b==5or`a-b`in"0-5"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLDsIgFET3fsWkKx@XBFC6aMKXYJNClEii0NC78euxbdzMmTOLmb/8Klm3aO/t7T/h4eEpDP4SrDWlTl6EKeVOCtM1fi68wMI5RbiNBKckQcm9Ea4be4L@e79RaLNOa6pxPMRSwUgZ@9Mw15QZTIjHM5/aDw)

Since I didn't manage to read the task carefully the first time, in order to fix it, I had to come up with a completely different approach, which is unfortunately not as concise.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes (or 34)

```r
function(x,y)any((-1:1*5)%in%c(x+y,x-y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdBCoAgEEDRfaeYjTBTM5BpJdFlQhDcGESBnt4QXL3/nxrglBq@5N94J8xc6EoFUfShx5VUTMpjngpnKUQ1oGbYaAhoGEzXNV1/sQuD2L31zJrqDw)

For non-R users:

- `-1:1*5` expands to `[-5, 0, 5]`
- the `%in%` operator takes elements from the left and checks (element-wise) if they exist in the vector on the right

A direct port of [@ArBo's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178803/79980) has <s>35</s> 34 bytes, so go upvote that answer if you like it:

```r
function(x,y)x%in%c(y--1:1*5,5-y)
```

Comment: The 34 byte one can be reduced by 1 with `function(x,y)x%in%c(y--1:1*5,5-y)`

Comment: Can drop to 30 bytes by moving the subtraction: `function(x,y)(x-y)%in%(-1:1*5)`, and drop it further to 24 bytes by dropping the function notation to `scan()` input: `diff(scan())%in%(-1:1*5)` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyUzLU2jODkxT0NTUzUzT1VD19DKUMtU87@uiRGXron5fwA "R – Try It Online").

Still very much the same method though.

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar does that account for the sum being 5?

Comment: @ArBo Hah, missed that in the spec, and there wasn't a test case in the TIO so I just glossed over it!

Comment: Minor change that can be made to both is to use `pryr::f`, which happens to work in both cases. Whether it can properly detect the arguments is entirely somewhat hit or miss but it seems to nail these two functions. e.g. `pryr::f(x%in%c(y--1:1*5,5-y))` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@7@gqLLIyipNo0I1M081WaNSV9fQylDLVMdUt1JT83@ahqGOgokmF5g2A9HGOgrGUNoCRFtA@bomRjoKuibmILaBjqHmfwA "R – Try It Online").

Gets you to 36 and 29 bytes respectively.

Comment: This fails on (3, -3) - returns True because they sum to 0.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to Adám*

```
1#.=+5=|@-,+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1PC4IwHL37KR4G/Ryu5Sw9bEyEwFOn6B5hmkoo2DoE0Vdfkw7vH7zHG1woQC2MAoEjgfLYCBxOx8rJlTBxZj7lhseOBXZ@2e69VHe@Rn0r8MZt8ns6z6@GCM3j2Syxunqz5PEmKLD1stlDaplAJlpip3OkXnN9SbMcnmTQ1N1URgRTgIapH5927sd7qHQUqvJ/zYkR/xIi4qFiZdRuGVuLArZ2Pw)

### Explanation

This is equivalent to:

```
1 #. = + 5 = |@- , +
```

This can be divided into the following fork chain:

```
(= + (5 e. (|@- , +)))
```

Or, visualized using `5!:4<'f'`:

```
  ┌─ =               
  ├─ +               
──┤   ┌─ 5           
  │   ├─ e.          
  └───┤          ┌─ |
      │    ┌─ @ ─┴─ -
      └────┼─ ,      
           └─ +
```

Annotated:

```
  ┌─ =                                     equality
  ├─ +                                     added to (boolean or)
──┤   ┌─ 5                                   noun 5
  │   ├─ e.                                  is an element of
  └───┤          ┌─ |  absolute value         |
      │    ┌─ @ ─┴─ -  (of) subtraction       |
      └────┼─ ,        paired with            |
           └─ +        addition               | any of these?
```

Comment: Save a byte with `e.`

Comment: @Adám How so? Shortest approach I got with `e.` was `=+.5 e.|@-,+`. Maybe you forget `5e.` is an invalid token in J?

Comment: Since two integers cannot simultaneously sum to 5 and be equal, you can use `+` instead of `+.`

Comment: @Adám Ah, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 38 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @DjMcMayhem

```python
lambda a,b:a+b==5or abs(a-b)==5or a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUTvJ1tY0v0ghMalYI1E3SRPKs7VN@l9QlJlXopGmYahjoqn5HwA)

Comment: Your TIO is actually 42 bytes but you can fix it by deleting the spaces between the `5`s and the `or`s

Comment: Actually, the TIO link could be [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUTvJ1tY0v0ghMalYI1E3SRPKs7VN@l9QlJlXopGmYahjoqn5HwA)

Comment: @ElPedro the function itself was 40 bytes but I used f= in order to be able to call it

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I don't normally golf in python. I just did it because the question asker used python for their example

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcsxCoAwDIXh3VN0bDAZqq2I0Ju4JEhR0Crq4unraOv4vZ93PPe8xyYFP6aVN5lYMcrg1BI114Isl2YSgP1U7L2k41zirYM2aACqTzaT/bUuU1c06pFMmw0NUlt8c5FDB5Be "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$b-in($a-5),(5-$a),(5+$a),$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyVJNzMPyNY11dTRMNVVSQRR2iBKJfH///@6RqZmIMIQAA) or [Verify all Test Cases](https://tio.run/##ZZBfa4MwFMXf8ylSyEbCElBXfRsIhcGeWljfShmxTalFjTVxZXR@dneNzlZ6H3KS3zk3/0p9UZU5qixrSYHf8LUtZSVzSiQnCSOJSAuYi5BxGgoiO3nphMi2QSimCEPFdM6xKx/UZ3ygvuewkzs6ZF9BvZFGAw0m9D8bTXYQQRhxGKanRZM7IIZ/8dPVeZvV56I2VufL5KR2dhv3uKtDWhn7UZS1hceTr423HS2jdrrY33n@zdO17TF9hm9zfX2CjZFvmaX71P6slbHLMf6Qx0Kd8WwGi2BoblADV3/XVS6tWMskU@0f)

Takes input `$a` and `$b`. Checks if `$b` is `-in` the group (`$a-5`, `5-$a` `5+$a`, or `$a`), which checks all possible combinations of `$a`,`$b`, and `5`.

*-4 bytes thanks to mazzy.*
*-4 bytes thanks to KGlasier.*

Comment: `($a-$b)` is `-$x` :)

Comment: @mazzy Ooo, good call.

Comment: If you switch `5` and `$b` around you can cut off a couple bytes(ie `param($a,$b)$b-in($a-5),(5-$a),($a+5),$a`) [Try it out here](https://tio.run/##ZZBRS8MwEMff8ykyyCTBBNpq@yYUhMGeJri3MeS6Ray0Tdekisx@9nqmtVvxHnK53/9/ySW1@dSNfdNF0bOKPtBzX0MDJWcgWSZYpvIK9yoWkseKASYGt1gx6DtCUk4oRsrvJfURYg6FHGkYeOzTFR29d5iDiSYjjWb0z5vMTlBRnEhc5rclsxmIoN90efba7un5sbXOlJvsXR/cPh3wb7zmjXXrqm4dPp697IL9JFl9MNXxSgsvmmndgPkNfpvvGxxisnxAkR9z97XV1m0m@z8/VfpEFwssorG5Ix2OvjJNCU5tISt0/wM)

Comment: @KGlasier Excellent suggestion. I needed to swap `$a+5` to `5+$a` to get it to cast appropriately when taking command-line input, but otherwise awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

Takes input as `[a][b]`.

```
MatchQ[#|5-#|#-5|#+5]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYjBCoQgFEV/5cKDNimkZbsGf2Cg1uJCoqhFLQZ36rc7Gm3uOedezh/b5fy5urxjyl/n12MxFBWnSFxFapVt8vw7b28CUQL/YDdkDUlr0UBrjRAGBpEYguiKdI8x9JUjg3x7rORSlausSCn/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 30 bytes

```java
a->b->a+b==5|a==b|(b-=a)*b==25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBLi4MwGLz7Kz4KQtJVUXftod14XNjDwkKP0kN8lbgaxXwWSutvd@ODpV0DSSYzk8mQgl@4XaQ/g6iaukUo9NnpUJTO9mCsuLyTCYpajmJScqXgiwsJNwOg6eJSJKCQo94utUih0ho5YivkOToBb8@KTlaAT4kfS9S7xt9tloqEYxZCDgwGboexHfKXmLHgzhmL7yS2GadbTfjBcJgyhMTopHMxU6j0rTl5HDd4s8CD3npgPFdT7j/OgtdnZmeBv/LsnhnbD7RNr97q7gPTzyXzuiVT0anmfi5L/7oerwqzyqk7dBr9TZiTjZmCme7BVKbcWJM/ck8L8DTIHd405ZUsCnVGQBaZ0vnZ3hhnP/wC)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 24 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Grimy*

```perl6
{$^a-$^b==5|0|-5|5-2*$b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwAEPv/YocZOiw0ta1t7rbvmC3oqCswkCn1MkY1m/v3EVDCHkQMlrXqdB/cWqhEZaoqmlUNVpLzzyVXlJxjpo1tIND3D1fdkqKIvsM7jFhIdg0zm@Yaxv7zLCUl0maGZHmZUnWcAGHLnB3syWcYfNOyP/9VneTJQriAA61r6iQClscL@p4/AE)

This uses the Any Junction but technically, `^` could work as well.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                      }  # Anonymous code block
 $^a-$^b==                # Is the difference equal to
           | |  |        # Any of
          0 
            5
              -5
                 5-2*$b
```

Comment: -1 byte with `{$^a-$^b==5|0|-5|5-2*$b}`

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>21</del> 20 bytes

```
00000000: 8bd0 2bc3 740d 7902 f7d8 3c05 7405 03d3  ..+.t.y...<.t...
00000010: 80fa 05c3                                ....
```

Listing:

```
8B D0       MOV  DX, AX     ; Save AX to DX 
2B C3       SUB  AX, BX     ; AX = AX - BX 
74 0D       JZ   DONE       ; if 0, they are equal (ZF=1) 
79 02       JNS  IS_POS     ; if positive, check if result is 5
F7 D8       NEG  AX         ; is negative, negate the result to get abs value
        IS_POS: 
3C 05       CMP  AL, 5      ; is result 5?
74 05       JZ   DONE       ; if so, exit with ZF=1
03 D3       ADD  DX, BX     ; DX = DX + BX
80 FA 05    CMP  DL, 5      ; ZF = ( DX == 5 )
        DONE:
C3          RET             ; return to caller
```

Input numbers in `AX` and `BX` and returns Zero Flag (`ZF`) if result is truthy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVThUuJIEP6deYqu1LoQnSBB8WpBtERwva1VLNEry41FDckAuQ0TLjPReC7P7vUMiYi1l4LJ9HT3191fd2bM5Ow1YAoOD/uDMziCXTVf7LIak3Nog9Avd8LjyV7jvcZNVlKQhLyWoCEPZgnYhOeKpwIioWA0Ykql0ThTfDSqVidMqoDFsePAJBNBFU0o/p02kDmLRNV5IdpLcankj4fOi0/2qUeJV6f4Ix7do@SANvTugBK30TyguHj60CPLNpkkqYaEqFNvR4cy@pcnk6oBc3YLyUSLdjoNDLVIUZpUfXsrpFthC7akL3ybrqJHD@Vmx3ugJtvfKJxj375JM@7bLd8@Y7HEndMmS7K0Sxalysa1oO0Tn0yDYJM0pPS90QadrkjcRcTBne81jHcy/jvM5gtwe@BeaHZ5vOFw9PmDndxQ/0JaORxVdZs9tHV@wTTlaNaHyo@6@@XhZX8JFTQLMgXuGP5w9xvaKQU3hIovKmvBmGk0gz/jeU3lCo@esLwA3@zpJ1ReDL3wydttLLX9im2wfbG9vd19VhyCJBOqhZIvNPU2fDLJuc5bKWagXF44nfNcF6Y9bGMCeR6CizktPmaiFSXIBt2vkgcqSgTUFI4psaZxMmaxmUail5aFTxvZXWRKapL3GiOFg50DEyHwMCdQPHen51@hf3JHoX96B9qJhWyhoJxxUAlSKVUyBy1GYooFi0cudPgPKF2N0rsjxLoY/AV6SzW0QR2yRw64Rzi0sIa3XSjCdlcGqOvoxYUu6r/dI2pvcNk3umgCdQpqxoVenoGlHPg/GVZcvT/reA7aXw4B/hyOrgbD0mORyEhFj5xCMOPBT32UcpnF@GFJaBKwLvtf4S0/PBN8ylYOZsd1rNIF055yBWws4ZHFGSerWC1inV5cAZx8p9AsYAqP5vFvqpAJBZ5HCp4iNQOdO7FOer2Sq4KKnqYClx1DhQnQ0wFKlCY1rhbR0JiC9a5tqW7U//UL8GrB/FSWihYUfob3@zM4Bg9aUH9rqckdq7y5vu2XDOEdoWbPmnTneN37wXXZypLLCZhL5JmCRNJMhDXwdf@GFLitt8Or2@E5eGtxcLVuDUeodfR3mB5OGqK94mX/@h8) (testing code borrowed and adapted from [@Logem's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178821/84624) - thanks!)

*Explanation:*

If the difference between the numbers is 0, they are equal. Otherwise if result is negative, first negate it (abs value) and check for 5.  If still not true, add and check for 5.

*Bonus:*

If desired, you can also determine which condition was true with the following:

- `ZF` = `1` and `DX` = `5`  ; sum is 5
- `ZF` = `1` and `AX` = `5`   ; diff is 5
- `ZF` = `1` and `AX` = `0`     ; equal
- `ZF` = `0`            ; falsey

Answer (score 4):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <del>26</del> 70 bytes

**Edit:** + input variables.

```pascal
Procedure z(a,b:integer);begin Writeln((abs(a-b)in[0,5])or(a+b=5))end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBCsIwEIXhvafIcgYTsYUiGHoHdy7ExSQdQ6AmYVpBvHysitDdB@/xF5o8jeZWfC2Sg9BdPW09SfY8PITVC0i7Y0wzBxa0jkNM6ixx5jEBkJuAjMOYLnvdXTEL0Nb1HSKnwdbve7M0mlY3LdoPzUGblf9c67cvhV19Aw)

---

```pascal
(abs(a-b)in[0,5])or(a+b=5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCsIwDADQ@74ixxZXUWEIjv2Elx3EQ9JlpVC7ko7h1xt7fa9g9ZjcWrwW2YLgB75jBwcKYE@PmHcOLE2IQ8wdwJNxSdm0tE1hlrizUYNUDTqyMb8u/fC2mxg80TRYtSNwXs7q7uCuN/j5NWGo@gc)

I hope that my answer is according to all rules of code-golf. It was fun anyway.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Normally, you have to take input, instead of assuming it is already in variables. I don't know Pascal, but I think that is what this code is doing.

Comment: Hello, NoOneIsHere and thank you for the remark. It was may concern too - shall I include the initialization of the variables. Looking at several other solutions, like Java for example, where the function definition with parameters was excluded from the total length of the solution, I decided not to include ReadLn.

Comment: Alright. Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: The Java submission is an anonymous lambda which takes two parameters. This appears to use predefined variables, which is not a valid method of input.

Comment: No problem, I will change my submission.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>43</s>, <s>48</s>, <s>47</s>, 33 bytes

EDIT:  Tried to use % and apparently forgot how to %.  Thanks to Arnauld for pointing that out!

EDIT2:  AdmBorkBork with a -1 byte golf rearranging the parentheses to sit next to the return so no additional space is needed!

EDIT3:  Thanks to dana for -14 byte golf for the one-line return shortcut and currying the function (Ty Embodiment of Ignorance for linking to TIO).

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 33 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>a==b|a+b==5|(a-b)*(a-b)==25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc2xCgIxDAbgvU@RsVVPVKyL5hbBSUFwcE57VQq1lWtPEPXZz54Obh6BP4F8JDoWOtSmbaL1ZzjcYzKXJdOOYoR9Hc41XR4M4NooZzXERCm3W7AV7Mh6LrolwKbxemV9Gv0mFYIrS6gAW8JSYUmI6klDhSifnAolBp9EnMl2yb6fx@vgY3BmfKxtMlvrDa@4FHwqhfhrphPB@8xcdKznTjY9pJjJrHIuOsjYK1d7amzlIrkTvQE)

Comment: Bah.  Trying to avoid System.Math.  Back to it!  Thanks for pointing that out :D

Comment: You can get it down to [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##hc2xCgIxDAbgvU@RsVVPVKyL5hbBSUFwcE57VQq1lWtPEPXZz54Obh6BP4F8JDoWOtSmbaL1ZzjcYzKXJdOOYoR9Hc41XR4M4NooZzXERCm3W7AV7Mh6LrolwKbxemV9Gv0mFYIrS6gAW8JSYUmI6klDhSifnAolBp9EnMl2yb6fx@vgY3BmfKxtMlvrDa@4FHwqhfhrphPB@8xcdKznTjY9pJjJrHIuOsjYK1d7amzlIrkTvQE "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") applying dana's tips

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 43 bytes

```scala
def f(a:Int,b:Int)=a+b==5|(a-b).abs==5|a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcyxCoMwFAXQ3a94SIeEajFaHQopdOzQj3jRCBaJ0mQoqN@eJoGiRZrhQi7nXV1jj3YQT1kbeGCnQL6NVI2G2zjCFNlGttASvNyVSYRPyvEoOC/nmWAq6AmFDj/kXFiA8dUp0yui43MC7jEf/AqHqSWuYXSJabRlLPOOZSvzDcv2MOwVmz3XFDtWBZZvmGvyP2vV71q1Y2leunOX7MvWJuDFfgA)

Comment: Isn't it possible to golf the `||` to `|`? I know it's possible in Java, C#, Python, or JavaScript, but not sure about Scala.

Comment: Actually yes! thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
OIÆ‚Ä50SåZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3/Nw26OGWYdbTA2CDy@N@v8/WtfQyFAHSJjFAgA)

---

```
O           # Sum the input.
 IÆ         # Reduced subtraction of the input.
   ‚        # Wrap [sum,reduced_subtraction]
    Ä       # abs[sum,red_sub]
     50S    # [5,0]
        å   # [5,0] in abs[sum,red_sub]?
         Z  # Max of result, 0 is false, 1 is true.
```

Tried to do it using stack-only operations, but it was longer.

Comment: This will unfortunately return true if the sum is `0` such as for `[5, -5]`

Comment: Your other 10-byte solution that you left as a comment (`OIÆÄ‚5QIËM`) is correct for `[5,-5]`.

Comment: Another 10-byte solution that I came up with is `OsÆÄ‚5åsË~`. Almost identical to yours it seems. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9ua6XLf//iw22HWx41zDI9vLT4cHfd///R0SY6hrE60YYGOoYGIFrHGEia6RiB2WZAUtfI1EwHSBiCxUGkrqmOaWwsAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 33 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=!(a+b-5&&(a-=b)/6|a%5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCsIwEETv@YoasGTpBttqIxiDN7/AW@lhE6jkYBWtp5pvj9uBGRgewwR9DyHnURF6WMhtFFVed2WpSDsPO/OjbQc25QfFSUGxiDjNBfWDWw7Y1NigYeu2M2gSioLlV9iscI8tY4bckhXj863WdXS1jeejjVUF4vWdP4rv@zig54CLvMmTvEqwIuU/)

Tried an approach I didn't see anyone else try using. The return expression is equivalent to `a+b==5||((-6<a-b||a-b<6)&&(a-b)%5==0)`.

---

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
=|+5|-ȧ5
```

Takes input as a list of two numbers (use `_` for negatives). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/37ZG27RG98Ry0///ow11zGIB)

#### Explanation

Pretty much a direct translation of the spec:

```
=          The two numbers are equal
 |         or
  +        The sum of the two numbers
   5       is 5
    |      or
     -     The difference of the two numbers
      ȧ    absolute value
       5   is 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>41</s> 34 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=5==abs(a-b)|a+b==5|a==b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM60dbU1jYxqVgjUTdJsyZRO8nW1rQm0dY2ybr2f25iZp6GJlc1l4KCQkFpSbFGmoahkY6hgaa9UkhRaaqSlZJbYk5xqpKmNReyEh0TLAqQ5A2wG4FsghkW@dr/AA)

Comment: Why does `f` return `a`? Just some Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @Tyilo Yes, it's implementation specific.  So happens the first parameter is stored in the same register as the return value.

Comment: [30 bytes Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM60VbX1NY2UTepJlE7ydbWtCbR1jbJuvZ/bmJmnoYmVzWXgoJCQWlJsUaahqGRjqGBpr1SSFFpqpKVkltiTnGqkqY1F7ISHRMsCpDkDbAbgWyCGV55XSNTMx0gYYhFVe1/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Logern Doesn't work for f(6,1)

Comment: @ceilingcat Doesn't work for f(6,1)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM60dZUNzGpWCNRN0lTTS1RO0nXFEjpJlnX/s9NzMzT0OSq5lJQUCgoLSnWSNMwNNIxNNC0VwopKk1VslJyS8wpTlXStOZCVqJjgkUBkrwBdiOQTTDDIl/7HwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat The logic is reversed. It returns false when it should return true.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
ÐO5Qs`α5QrËO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8AR/08DihHMbTQOLDnf7//8frWtkaqYDJAxjAQ)

Takes input as a list of integers, saving one byte. Thanks @Wisław!

## Alternate 12 byte answer

```
Q¹²α5Q¹²+5QO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8NDOQ5vObTQF09qmgf7//@samZpxAQlDAA)

This one takes input on separate lines.

Comment: Since it is not very clearly specified, can you not assume the input is a list of integers, thus eliminating the initial `|`?

Comment: @Wisław Good point, I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I found a 11 bytes alternative: `OI\`αª5¢IË~Ā`. Input is a list of integers.

Comment: `OIÆÄ)5QIËM` is 10.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm not sure exactly what the rules are but I think your solution is different enough from mine to submit your own answer, no? Also, unrelated but I've seen your username on this site for a long time but only after typing it out did I realize that it's "Urn", not "Um" :)

Comment: I already posted a different solution, but that's the one I got to while playing with yours so feel free to use it. Also I've always been annoyed at that `rn=m` with the SE font lol! Magic Octopus Urn is an anagram for my `last_name+computing`. Dennis chose it for me out of a list of anagrams.

Comment: Should've gone with `Mr Contagious Cup`, `Magic Coupon Rust`, or `Narcotic Gum Soup`

Answer (score 2):

### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 34 Bytes

```
->(a,b){[a+5,a-5,5-a,a].include?b}
```

[Online Eval](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jUSdJszo6UdtUJ1HXVMdUN1EnMVYvMy85pzQl1T6p9n@BQlq0iY6CYSwXiGVoAGQaQNk6CsYQlpmOghFczAzC0jUyBQoDSUO4GigLaI2Caex/AA)
-  Thanks @ASCII-Only

Comment: do you check if they're equal though...

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that check. Thanks @ASCII-only for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: i'd be nice if you could link to [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jUSdJszo6UdtUJ1HXVMdUN1EnMVYvMy85pzQl1T6p9n@BQlq0iY6CYSwXiGVoAGQaQNk6CsYQlpmOghFczAzC0jUyBQoDSUO4GigLaI2Caex/AA)

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jUSdJszo6UdtUJ1HXVMdUN1EnMVYvMy8ltUIhqfZ/gUJatImOgmEsF4hlaABkGkDZOgrGEJaZjoIRXMwMwtI1MgUKA0lDuBooC2iJgmnsfwA) _might_ be valid? not completely sure though, you might wanna check with someone else

Comment: This will work but it requires `.nil?` check to give output in the required format. 
`->(a,b){[a+5,a-5,5-a,a].index(b).nil?}`, this is longer than the current one.

Comment: Oh yeah, the question says "return true"

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @chunes!

```
[ { [ = ] [ - abs 5 = ] [ + 5 = ] } || ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYi9CgIxEAZ7n@LrJQGFs1CsxcZGrI4r9pbIBfNzbNZCPJ89prhmmJknsWapj/v1djmCcxx9onaKLVMWNeyF315tiSSKl5PkAiLphFmc6mcWnxSnjdl3BzTsao8vepwxNBrQWNCttV3th2XBUJlCgK1/)

The repetition of `=` is annoying, but I couldn't find another way.

`||` tries out each of the three quotations in `{...}` and checks if the result is true for any of them. The first, `[ = ]`, checks if they're equal, the second finds the absolute value of their difference and compares that to 5, and the third compares their sum to 5.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes with `||`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYi9CgIxEAZ7n@LrJQGFs1CsxcZGrI4r9pbIBfNzbNZCPJ89prhmmJknsWapj/v1djmCcxx9onaKLVMWNeyF315tiSSKl5PkAiLphFmc6mcWnxSnjdl3BzTsao8vepwxNBrQWNCttV3th2XBUJlCgK1/ "Factor – Try It Online")

Comment: @chunes Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
¥VªaU ¥5ª5¥Nx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9DSsEOrEkMVDi01PbTK9NBSv4r//w0VzAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 53 bytes

```
proc P a\ b {expr abs($a-$b)==5|$a==$b|abs($a+$b)==5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxCoNAEAX7/YpXbGEIgmv0uvsH@8RiV@wMHmpAOO/bL4I2MzAw2zDlHJZ5QAf9wBDHPSxQWwvWku3hfXuwes92XPF5xZSnr4b7oQZCUkEqErzIoT7tqKxbhxNCCTH8thXvDqxg61P@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
x ¥5|50ìøUra
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=eCClNXw1MOz4VXJh&input=WzQsMV0=) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=eCClNXw1MOz4VXJh&input=WwpbNCwxXQpbMTAsMTBdClsxLDNdCls2LDJdClsxLDZdClstMjU2LC0yNTFdClstNSw1XQpdCi1tUg==)

```
x ¥5|50ìøUra
                 :Implicit input of array U
x                :Reduce by addition
  ¥5             :Equal to 5?
    |            :Bitwise OR
     50ì         :Split 50 to an array of digits
        ø        :Contains?
         Ur      :  Reduce U
           a     :    By absolute difference
```

Comment: Fails for `[-5,5]` (should be falsey)

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen. Rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 81 bytes

```
@set/as=%1+%2,d=%1-%2
@if %d% neq 0 if %d:-=% neq 5 if %s% neq 5 exit/b
@echo 1
```

Takes input as command-line arguments and outputs 1 on success, nothing on failure. Batch can't easily do disjunctions so I use De Morgan's laws to turn it into a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｎθ¿№⟦θ⁺⁵θ⁻⁵θ⁻θ⁵⟧Ｎ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orM01Bwzm/NK9EI7pQRyEgp7RYw1RHoVBTR8E3Mw@dA1Rhqhmro4BsiKampkJAUSbQACVDJU3r//91jUzNFICE4X/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @ArBo's Python 2 solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 82 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^(-?1*) \1$|^(-?1*)1{5} -?\2$|^-?(-?1*) (\3)1{5}$|^-?(1 ?){5}$|^(1 ?-?){5}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYmxDkAwFEX39xVvIGnJS9yWrh39RCMkDBaD2PDtVWq5955z9@VYtymWqh9jmGsqKhqUeFSaA4rr3zi7m8UHk4z4/1fBfkd2YK8zvFMyxNgyCA2jIbAlxya1IzGd4xRIBg8) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first two lines convert the inputs into unary. The final line then checks for any of the permitted matches:

```
^(-?1*) \1$                              x==y
^(-?1*)1{5} -?\2$   x>=0 y>=0 x=5+y i.e. x-y=5
                    x>=0 y<=0 x=5-y i.e. x+y=5
                    x<=0 y<=0 x=y-5 i.e. y-x=5
^-?(-?1*) (\3)1{5}$ x<=0 y<=0 y=x-5 i.e. x-y=5
                    x<=0 y>=0 y=5-x i.e. x+y=5
                    x>=0 y>=0 y=5+x i.e. y-x=5
^-?(1 ?){5}$        x>=0 y>=0 y=5-x i.e. x+y=5
                    x<=0 y>=0 y=5+x i.e. y-x=5
^(1 ?-?){5}$        x>=0 y>=0 x=5-y i.e. x+y=5
                    x>=0 y<=0 x=5+y i.e. x-y=5
```

Pivoted by the last column we get:

```
x==y            ^(-?1*) \1$
x+y=5 x>=0 y>=0 ^-?(1 ?){5}$
      x>=0 y>=0 ^(1 ?-?){5}$
      x>=0 y<=0 ^(-?1*)1{5} -?\2$
      x<=0 y>=0 ^-?(-?1*) (\3)1{5}$
      x<=0 y<=0 (impossible)       
x-y=5 x>=0 y>=0 ^(-?1*)1{5} -?\2$
      x>=0 y<=0 ^(1 ?-?){5}$
      x<=0 y>=0 (impossible)
      x<=0 y<=0 ^-?(-?1*) (\3)1{5}$
y-x=5 x>=0 y>=0 ^-?(-?1*) (\3)1{5}$
      x>=0 y<=0 (impossible)
      x<=0 y>=0 ^-?(1 ?){5}$
      x<=0 y<=0 ^(-?1*)1{5} -?\2$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 48 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(find 5(list(abs(- b a))a(+ a b)b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator), 90 bytes

A pretty straightfoward solution, could definitely by golfed further:

```
f(a,b)=\left\{a+b=5:0,1\right\}\left\{\left|a-b\right|=5:0,1\right\}\left\{a=b:0,1\right\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxsz9emyts)

[image]

0 is true, and 1 is false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
}5[sQaFQ+4l{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9Y0ujgw0S1Q2ySn@v9/QwMdBUMDAA)

```
}5[sQaFQ+4l{
}5[sQaFQ+4l{Q) // Implicit input and closed brace
  [          ) // Create an array of the following:
   sQ          //   Sum of input
     aFQ       //   Absolute difference of input
        +4l{Q  //   Length of unique values in input, + 4
}5             // Is '5' in the array?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
=£₌+ĸW5c¥∨
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3D%C2%A3%E2%82%8C%2B%C4%B8W5c%C2%A5%E2%88%A8&inputs=9%0A4&header=&footer=)

#### Credits

- Saved 1 byte thanks to @Lyxal by employing the use of an absolute difference built-in

Comment: [10 bytes ;p](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3D%C2%A3%E2%82%8C%2B%C4%B8W5c%C2%A5%E2%88%A8&inputs=9%0A4&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
|!!/,a.*QsQ5q.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v0ZRUV8nUU8rsDjQtFBP6/9/Ex0FSwA)

Not super impressed, especially having to use double negation `!!` to cast a number into `true`... I'm sure there's a better way.

```
|!!/,a.*QsQ5q.*
   /,      5     Count '5's in: 
     a.*Q        Absolute value of (A, B)
         sQ      Sum of (A, B)
 !!              Cast to truthy
|                OR:
            q.*  A==B
```

Comment: Doh, I already solved this one several months ago and did it in 12 chars... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215521/97730

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 37 bytes

```
[ 2dup + 5 = -rot - abs "\0"in? or ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xC8IwEIUnl/yKR1eJtNF0sKijuLiIkzrEmmLRNiE5Byn97bFFqT2O4/seb7hC5WRcOB52@@0SynuTezy0q/UTlaI7vCYP6zTR27qyJmSMNQzdNFggQfvjJO53MMwHTiFGeTowFzLtTzJq/plLyE5aFk4Qt5fFtPMVuDMEDnX1iM7xJCrrDYzDJRTf59eVspiFDw)

### Explanation

`"\0"` Has literal `0` and `5` embedded in the string (you can see it on TIO). So `"\0"in?` is equivalent to `{ 0 5 } member?` In other words, checking whether the input is 0 or 5.

```
          ! -256 -251
2dup      ! -256 -251 -256 -251
+         ! -256 -251 -507
5         ! -256 -251 -507 5
=         ! -256 -251 f
-rot      ! f -256 -251
-         ! f -5
abs       ! f 5
"\0"in?   ! f t
or        ! t
```

Answer (score 1):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 33 bytes

```
:{:}=?;:{:}+5=?;-:0(?!u01-*O5=?;.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/9@q2qrW1t4aRGmbAhm6VgYa9oqlBoa6Wv4gvt7////yC0oy8/OK/@tm2hqaKhgaAQA)

Could be lower if handling negative numbers wasn't a requirement. Uses the exit code as its truthy/falsey.

Initializes the stack with the `-i` flag, but this method can't handle negatives. The above code still works, but you must prepend your starting values to the start of the script. For example, the following works with the stack of `[-15, 12]`

```
53*0-c:{:}=?;:{:}+5=?;-:0(?!u01-*O5=?;.
```

### Explanation

```
:{:}                                Duplicate the two values on the stack
    =?;                             If they're equal, halt execution
       :{:}                         Duplicate the two values on the stack, again
           +                        Add them together
            5=                      Check if that value is equal to 5
              ?;                    If so, halt execution
                -:                  Else, subtract our two values, and duplicate the result
                  0(                Check if the difference is less than 0
                    ?!u             If it is greater than 0, Dive and ignore instructions until we reach a Rise
                       01-*         If it isn't, multiply it by -1
                            O       Rise from our previous Dive. Ignored if there was no Dive.
                             5=     Check if our difference is equal to 5
                               ?;   If so, halt execution
                                 .  Else, throw an error
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 27 bytes

```
i::i::}3s=?!@-'|A5:}=?!@+=@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TygqIao2Lbe0VHXTVaxxNrWpBTG1bh///zRUMjQA)

Outputs `0` (exactly one zero) for false and any other output (literally whatever is left on the stack) for true.

New interpreter build, updated answer, saved 3 bytes (previous revision miscounted and said 4).

#### Explanation:

```
i::i::                         Read two inputs, duplicating each twice.
      }                        Rotate stack right
       3s                      Rotate the top 3 items to the right
         =? @                  Compare equal, if so, dump stack
           !                   If not, skip next instruction
             -'|A              Subtract, absolute value, (j)
                 5:}           Push two 5s, rotate one to the bottom
                    =? @       Compare 5 with (j), if equal, dump stack
                      ! +=     If not, add the two inputs, compare with remaining 5
                          @    Dump stack (will be 1 for true and 0 for false)
```

Essentially it reads both inputs 3 times and arranges the stack so that each operation works on a copy of each input (or a literal `5`). As the only way to dump a `0` is if all three comparisons are false, simply dumping the rest of the stack avoids having to do anything other than vomiting the entire stack to output and terminating, all posibilities of which are valid [truthy values](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190/47990).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

Pretty simple really, uses the `an` flags for input. Outputs 0 for false, 1 for true. Not gonna lie, I don't know if bitwise OR is appropriate here, but is does work for all the test cases, so that's nice.

```perl
($a,$b)=@F;print($a==$b|$a+$b==5|$a-$b==5|$b-$a==5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19DJVFHJUnT1sHNuqAoM68EyLe1VUmqUUnUVkmytTUFMnShjCRdkJyp5v//hgYKuqb/8gtKMvPziv/rJuYBAA)

Comment: bitwise OR is equivalent to logical OR when operating on one-bit values. In general, if passed a truthy arguments bitwise OR will return truthy, and if passed two falsy arguments bitwise OR will return 0.

Comment: [-11 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd42vSi1QFElXkclQVdFHUhqq6jrmurommonJhWDxf7/N1EwVLC1UwgpKk3lMjRQACI4T8EYxHZLzClO5TJTMEJwDBXM4Kp0jUzNFIAEwhQzJBN1TRVM4fr@5ReUZObnFf/XLcgBAA)

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WJcHWVkW9Jr0otUA/zlRFX0clQVtFXScxqVglQVdF/f9/EwVDBVs7hZCi0lQuQwMFIILzFIxBbLfEnOJULjMFIwTHUMEMrkrXyNRMAUggTDFDMlHXVMEUru9ffkFJZn5e8X/dghwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
f(a,b)=((a+b-5)*(a-b)*(abs(a-b)-5))==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCoAgEITvPclureBaevNh9CAYItEP9PZmXUIvw3wzDMx6pej4LiWAI48WwE1eaBzBCf@qPz5XI7RWlm2P@UwZAizEiMPPLIllm9DcsCHV9aZhobShKtytWhaa6pfyAA)

Of course, it's probably not the shortest one

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS) 19 chars, 38 bytes

```
{∨/(⍺=⍵),5∊∣⍺+⍵,-⍵}

  f←{∨/(⍺=⍵),5∊∣⍺+⍵,-⍵}
  4 f 1
1
  1 f 3
0
  6 f 2
0
  1 f 6
1
  ¯256 f ¯251
1
  6 f 1
1
  ¯5 f 5
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (>=1.9), <s>23</s> 38 bytes

```
->(a,b){a==b or a+b==5 or(a-b).abs==5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw7DoAgEAV7TrGlRKGjXK9idom/BIXwKYzx7Ii93bzJy8TCV61LOS0gqLGjgeVNiAw@AvWMaBp1pFhq4tTmI6hd1zknbTd/BJ39tAv@cQG@rrbkHLRurcqAMC8)

It's an anonymous function, so the TIO has some extra code to take input and return the output. Put the two numbers on separate lines.

Returns `true` if they are equal or add to 5, or if their absolute difference is 5, and `false` if not.

Comment: :| it's longer than the other (older) one

Comment: also. [better link](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jUSdJszrR1jZJIb9IIVE7ydbWFMjSSNRN0tRLTCoGcmv/FyikReua6pjG/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 30 Bytes

```
a?b=elem 5[a-b+5,abs(a-b),a+b]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
₍+ε5c□≈∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oKNK861NWPilqHiiYjiiKgiLCIiLCI0LCAxXG4xMCwgMTBcbjEsIDNcbjYsIDJcbjEsIDZcbi0yNTYsIC0yNTFcbjYsIDFcbi01LCA1Il0=)